# LIKE operator in SQL Server not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following SQL query:

```
select
    zz.teststring TEST_STRING
    ,case when zz.teststring like 'JA%' then 'true' else 'false' end [JA%]
    ,case when zz.teststring like 'J%' then 'true' else 'false' end [J%]
    ,case when zz.teststring like 'JAA%' then 'true' else 'false' end [JAA%]
from 
    (select 'jaa' teststring) zz
```

which outputs

```
TEST_STRING      JA%       J%       JAA%
jaa              false     true     true
```

Upper/lower case makes no difference.

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could explain why the `JA%` returns false?

Comment: MSSql is case-insensitive

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName Not really, the databases, tables and columns can use case sensitive collations

Comment: In sqlfiddle it returns the expacted result

Comment: I can only get 3x true or 3x false, depending on collation. What collation do you use?

Comment: @JakubLortz Try with `COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_CI_AI`, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/3195/0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check  collation probably is set to Case Sensitive:

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/3189)**

```
select
zz.teststring TEST_STRING
,case when zz.teststring like 'JA%' then 'true' else 'false' end [JA%]
,case when zz.teststring like 'J%' then 'true' else 'false' end [J%]
,case when zz.teststring like 'JAA%' then 'true' else 'false' end [JAA%]
from (
    select 'jaa' teststring
) zz
```

For Case Insensitive add `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS`

```
select
zz.teststring TEST_STRING
,case when zz.teststring like 'JA%'  COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS then 'true' else 'false' end [JA%]
,case when zz.teststring like 'J%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS then 'true' else 'false' end [J%]
,case when zz.teststring like 'JAA%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS then 'true' else 'false' end [JAA%]
from (
    select 'jaa' teststring
) zz
```

**EDIT:**

But I wonder how you get your answer `false, true, true`?:

**[Demo2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/3191/0)**

```
select
zz.teststring TEST_STRING
,case when zz.teststring like 'JA%' then 'true' else 'false' end [JA%]
,case when zz.teststring like 'J%' then 'true' else 'false' end [J%]
,case when zz.teststring like 'JAA%' then 'true' else 'false' end [JAA%]
from (
    select 'jaa' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS teststring
) zz
```

#### Thanks [jarlh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3706016/jarlh) mystery is solved:

**COLLATE  Danish_Norwegian_CI_AI**

**[Demo3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/3195/0)**

With some languages 'aa' is treated as one character.

Comment: Awesome! Didn't think about that.

Comment: Some languages treat aa as one character.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks for tip, I recreate this case with `COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_CI_AI`. Good to learn sth new